# MySQL: Why using where on date column does not use index

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which has a column with type `Date` which is shown like `2020-06-30`

I want to find rows where year of the date column is 2020 in them. The problem is even though its indexed, when I run this:

`explain select * from table where YEAR(date_c) = 2020;`

the key and possible_keys are both null. what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a function on the column (`YEAR()`).  That generally precludes the use of an index.

Use direct date comparisons:

```
where date_c >= '2020-01-01' and date_c < 2021-01-01'
```

Note:  If the date is always in the past, the second part of the comparison is not needed.

Comment: It works but in a strange behavior, possible_keys is never null by using this method, when I query `where date_c > '2021-06-29' ` it works as expected but key is null when I query  `where date_c < '2021-06-29' ` . How is this possbile?

Comment: @omidh . . . You would seem to have `NULL` values for `possible_keys`.  That is a separate issue from whether or not an index gets used for the `where` clause.